# Signal Processing or Computer Science or Statistics?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, stackexchange

I have a question about my Signal Processing Stack Exchange post: [Obtaining n values from n-1 sensors](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35008/obtaining-n-values-from-n-1-sensors)

I'm interested in the Signal Processing aspect, but I see a overlap with the Computer Science and even with the Statistics Stack Exchange. Where does this question fit?

Related Questions:

- [Statistical testing of quantities particular to signal processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/statistical-testing-of-quantities-particular-to-signal-processing)
- [Where to draw the line between programming, signal processing, and mathematics?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/where-to-draw-the-line-between-programming-signal-processing-and-mathematics?rq=1)
- [Are questions on numerical analysis on-topic?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/are-questions-on-numerical-analysis-on-topic?rq=1)

Comment: There's also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Rule of thumb: If it's about how to compute something without caring about the metal or concrete implementation, [cs.SE] is a good place. Depending on the subject, any of a couple different sites may be a better fit, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your SE.DSP question is still not clear to me:

- Is there an ordinal variable (e.g. time) to help you with separating latent variables? Or is the problem purely instantaneous?
- How can you quantify "obtain fairly accurate composition"?
- What are your sensor characteristics (esp. regarding saturation)?

Your question, IMHO, is not yet precise enough, or sufficiently formalized to be able to locate it precisely in the Venn diagram of Statistics, Signal Processing, Data science or Computer Science, which overlap to some extend.

Without ordinal variable, I would put it closer to Statistics.